Create a tree array using string id in javascript
I have an array of comment and its replies as follows:
[
{
 id:"comment 1",
 data: "data1",
 parent: "comment 0"
},
{
 id:"comment 2",
 data: "data2",
 parent: "comment 1"
},
{
 id:"comment 3",
 data: "data3",
 parent: "comment 2"
}
]

What I want to achieve is an tree of array of replies as in the following format where the children array is created based on parent id in the object:
[
{
 id:"comment 1",
 data: "data1",
 parent: "comment 0"
 children: [
{
 id:"comment 2",
 data: "data2",
 parent: "comment 1"
 children: [
{
 id:"comment 3",
 data: "data3",
 parent: "comment 2"
 children: []
}
]
}]
}
]

I found solutions using is as integer but what i want is a traversal of objects with string type id

the type does not matter. for the duplicate link.

Ok let me try that one
